# Water Spray Simulation

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am working on a project where water needs to be sprayed so to form 60 deg full cone from the spray nozzle in an animation. I have tried it with inflow and v cylinder but when water leaves out it does not exapand to 60 deg as required. Can you please give m advise how to achieve that? I have done hollow cone spray with addition of obstacle but need full cone spray.

Answer (score 5):

Examining the [subject at hand](https://youtu.be/omeTcd9aMUk?t=25s), it appears a better way would be to use particle drops instead of a fluid system.

The resulting cone can be easily controled.

[image]

The movement can be setup convincingly.

[image]

1. Create an emitter object. Since we'll use the normal as emission, the concavity of this object will determine the outcoming angle.
   Add a subdivision surface modifier so that the normal direction won't appear stepped.

   Create a *density* weight group, in case you want more water to be emitted from the center.
   [image]
2. Add a particle system. Since particle don't have substeps in Blender, we need to increase the frame rate. I used 240 fps.
   [image]
3. Enter the vertex group as density for the emitter.
   [image]
4. Decrease the gravity value, since we have a faster frame rate. To make the emitter use the subdivision modifier, check **Use Modifiers**. I use about 15000 particles in a short burst from frame 1-80.
   [image]
5. During that burst, I want the particles to have more speed around frame 40 and less at the end. Hence, I animate the Emission value for the normal. I also added some random offset to fight the missing substeps.
   [image]
6. Create a cube and smooth subdive it (or use *to sphere). Use it as the particle object. Add some children to each particle. There should be lots of drops.
   [image]
7. In the compositing add vector blur. As a material I mixed Glossy and Refractions BSDF.

Sorry, the file is not in the finished state. Have fun.

[image]

Comment: Blender does support substeps for particles. They're located in the  Physics rollout > subframes

Comment: @Leander:I sincerely thank you for the above answer . The reason I need fluid simulation is to check the % wetting of the part being sprayed with water and to ensure that complete part is getting wet.