# How To Simulate Water Spray from Nozzle Such As Pressure Washer

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

[image]

I am using Blender 2.8 - How can I simulate water spray from a pressure washer nozzle and make the spray react to an object like in this picture? The spray bounces off the sidewalk.

I've tried using particles but can't seem to get the effect of the "smooth" look. Should this be done using smoke or a combination of both smoke and particles?

I need to animate this pressure washer scene and not for it to be just a picture. How can this be done? Eevee or Cycles? Thank you.

Comment: Smoke sim, maybe? I would suggest particles, but you said they didn't work.

Comment: you can see this too https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86599/water-spray-simulation/86610

Comment: Thank you -- I've already seen and downloaded that tutorial -- but could not get the result I'm needing for a smooth flowing look of water spray such as shown in picture for animation

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make the particles look smooth like the spray shown in picture. I've tried very small size particles over 100,000 of them using uv spheres but just look like dots and no blur effect. Tried enlarging the particles but then it just looks like big dots. How to get the blur effect smooth like water in picture?

Comment: Try turning on motion blur

Comment: The smoothness is likely due to motion blur. You could try and simulate this directly with very fast moving particles and motion blur, but it may be somewhat computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Found the best way to do this was with particles. Ended up using about 70,000 particles and added some children with it and bumped up the normal on the velocity of the particles to help with the speed of them. Motion blur was also needed to smooth the spray effect.