# How to make forced Smoke simulation like spray?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I know how to make a simple smoke simulation, but this is somewhat difficult for me to understand..

**Refer this picture:**
[image]
You can see the red and blue smoke coming out of that can or cylinder or whatever it is...You can see that there's a force from the can that makes the smoke appear **narrow** from bottom as soon as it goes on spreading around. I need that type of **hard** and **forced** smoke.

> I referred [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86599/water-spray-simulation) question, but it is about particle system and I can't
>   adopt that for this.

Please suggest me a way to do this..

Comment: Have you tried using force fields? The Wind force field might help you there.

Comment: I have tried it buddy, its not so perfect to what I need!

Comment: It probably requires masses of tweaking, if you up the velocity of the smoke emitter and up the speed too then it may look a bit more like you want.

Comment: Thats fine, but what about narrowing the smoke at the bottom?

Comment: Well if you ensure the smoke emitter is at the bottom end of a tube, you should be good to go.